# Pagination with retrofit and rxjava OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android, pagination, out-of-memory, retrofit2

I'm trying to implement pagination with myself manually. And I am doing exactly as in a [sample repository](https://github.com/codename95/Android-Pagination-with-RecyclerView). But there is some incomprehensible to me error (in Log below). My app can load only 2-3 pages and crashes.

**Log:**

```
06-03 09:55:30.457 22190-22423/example.me E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Process: example.me, PID: 22190
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 168210 byte allocation with 9792 free bytes and 9KB until OOM
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:64)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 168210 byte allocation with 9792 free bytes and 9KB until OOM
    at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:79)
    at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:207)
    at okio.Buffer.readString(Buffer.java:631)
    at okio.Buffer.readString(Buffer.java:614)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:254)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallObservable.subscribeActual(CallObservable.java:41)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10838)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10838)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Or sometimes:**

```
OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError
```

**Network requests code:**

```
EventApiService eventApiService = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
    compositeDisposable.add(eventApiService.getJson(citySlug, FIRST_PAGE_TO_LOAD)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::handleFirstEventsDataResponse, this::handleFirstEventsDataResponseError));
```

**Response handling code (First page):**

```
@Override
public void showData(ResponseData responseData) {
    this.events = responseData.getEvents();
    this.responseData = responseData;
    eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(responseData.getEvents(), eventClickListener);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
}
```

**Response handling code (Next pages):**

```
@Override
public void showAdditionalData(ResponseData responseData) {
    eventAdapter.removeLoadingItem();
    isLoading = false;
    eventAdapter.addData(responseData.getEvents());
    eventAdapter.addLoadingItem();
}
```

**Retrofit Building method:**

```
private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.addInterceptor(logging);
    OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

**What I tried to do:**

- `android:largeHeap="true"` in AndroidManifest. It lets load one more page at all.
- Replace RxJava requests to plain Retrofit2 - no strong reaction.
- Remove OkHttpClient from retrofit builder - no strong reaction.

**UPD:**

We found out that the reason is in image loading. I've added `fit().centerCrop()` and now it loads 5-7 pages and crashes. My image loading code snippet in adapter:

```
String imageUrl = "";
            try {
                imageUrl = event.getImages().get(0).getImageUrl();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (eventViewHolder.ivPhoto != null) {
                Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).fit().centerCrop().into(eventViewHolder.ivPhoto);
            }
```

**New crash log:**

```
06-03 10:32:07.791 17978-17986/example.me E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
06-03 10:32:08.438 17978-17986/example.me E/System: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
06-03 10:32:08.439 17978-18715/example.me E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-163055
Process: example.me, PID: 17978
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

Comment: are you using any image? if yes, please use picasso or glide to load images.

Comment: @minhazur yes, I use Picasso.

Comment: then, please check where you are subscribing rx events and disposing them.

Comment: @minhazur I checked pagination without images and it works perfectly. So, when I turn on them, it crashes. Also, images are not loading from 1.5 page. What problem it can be?

Comment: need to check your image loading flow

Comment: you dont compress images , call on Picasso when you load image `.fit().centerCrop` , that 100% avoid OOM

Comment: @Devit951 I've updated my answer

Comment: @minhazur I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you use HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY , then you try to download large file , will save all body in memory for log.

That's easy let to OOM .

Try to remove log body or just logging NONE , basic or header and try again.

And when you try to get large file can use @Streaming in retrofit2 like this.

```
@Streaming
@GET
fun downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(@Url fileUrl: String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Try to remove log body in here.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

Try this .

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when picasso is trying set image, the viewholder is already null. For debugging you can use picasso to load image independently and set image by yourself. Don't forget to check nullability before setting.

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //check nullability and set image

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

               }
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should to check viewholder on null? If yes, in "onSuccess()" it is always not null. And if it will be null, the error will be "NPE", isn't it?

Comment: can you please, use leak canary to check whether there is any leak.